# AnyDesk on Windows Server

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012, anydesk

My employees connect to work using RDP to a server. I want to monitor what work they are doing on the company's server. AnyDesk or TeamViewer do not work as request returns to same server. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RDP Shadowing is the most probable solution in this case. You can set RDP shadowing powers in GPEDIT.MSC at - `Policies -> Administrative Templates -> Windows components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Session Host -> Connections.` Then type in the command in cmd with administrative rights - 
`Mstsc.exe /shadow:<Session ID> /Control`

Get session id by this command - `query session`.